# Can i check whether the dropdown box or combobox does not contain a specific item?

Tags: vb.net

This code:

```
        If BunifuDropdown2.Items.Contains("30") And BunifuDropdown2.Items.Contains("31") Then
```

Checks the items if it contains the string 30 and 31

```
        Else
            BunifuDropdown2.RemoveItem("30")
            BunifuDropdown2.RemoveItem("31")
```

yes the "Else" can be use to check whether the item does not contain 30 and 31

```
        End If
    End If
```

the problem is if the 30 and 31 has been removed in the item, is it possible to check whether 30 and 31 is not in the item, by not using "Else" instead i wanna use "ElseIf" if its possible.

```
Example: ElseIf BunifuDropdown2.Items.CheckIfItcontains("30") And BunifuDropdown2.Items.CheckIfItcontains("31") Then
```

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand want you want to do. Can you click the edit link and clarify a bit.

Comment: i have another line of code that will remove the 31 and 30 in the items, what i want to do is check if 31 and 30 is not in the item(container) and use ElseIf to check if it doesn't exist and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
If YourCombobox.Items(ThisItemYouWantToCheck) Is Nothing Then
   'Do Something
Else If YourCombobox.Item(ThisItemYouWantToCheckAtTheSecondPlace) Is Nothing Then
   'Do Something
Else
   'Do Something
```

If I got the question right, that's what you need.

Comment: 'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Boolean'. Operands must be reference or nullable types.

Comment: Then take one '='.

Comment: Why do you need this anyway?

Comment: If that doesn't work with the '=', do it with the .Contains

Comment: Use `IsNothing(SomeObject)` if you want to check if an object is `Nothing` (`Null`)